# VBA UDF - Reverse Transpose

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create an Excel custom function that reverses the order of the default TRANSPOSE function.

To simplify my problem, I'm mainly looking to transpose data in A1:C1 and have it appear in A2:A4 in reverse order where the data in A1 appears in A4, B1 appears in A3, C1 appears in A2.

So far, I've created a function called "Reverse" that wraps around the default TRANSPOSE function to look like this: {Reverse(TRANSPOSE(A1:A3))}.

The code is as follows:

```
Function Reverse(SelectRange As Variant)

Dim InputArray() As Variant
Dim OutputArray() As Variant
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

InputArray() = SelectRange
ReDim OutputArray(1 To UBound(InputArray), 1)

For y = 1 To UBound(InputArray)
OutputArray(y, 1) = InputArray(UBound(InputArray) - y + 1, 1)
Next y

Reverse = OutputArray

End Function
```

However, this outputs 0's in A2:A4 rather than the desired values.  I've checked that OutputArray is populated correctly using the immediate window, but for whatever reason, its values fail to appear.

Answer (score 1):

Second dimension of `OutputArray` contains two indices - `0` and `1`. You are filling with values the latter, and Excel displays the former because you enter the formula in a single column.

You want `ReDim OutputArray(1 To UBound(InputArray), 1 to 1)`, or `Option Base 1` at the beginning of the module.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out a solution.  I created a separate subroutine that flips the order rather than keeping that code within the function and then I call the subroutine from the core function.

The following code is a slight modification from the previous code that I posted as it combines the features of "Reverse" and "TRANSPOSE" into one function "ReverseTranspose".  It only requires the input {ReverseTranspose(A1:A3)} in order to work.  I'm sure that this can be optimized better, but it's working as intended for me:

```
Function ReverseTranspose(SelectRange As Range)

Dim InputArray() As Variant

InputArray() = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(SelectRange.Value)

Call FlipArray(InputArray)

ReverseTranspose = InputArray

End Function
```

---

```
Sub FlipArray(InputArray As Variant)

Dim OutputArray() As Variant
Dim y As Integer

ReDim OutputArray(1 To UBound(InputArray), 1)

For y = 1 To UBound(InputArray)
OutputArray(y, 1) = InputArray(UBound(InputArray) - y + 1, 1)
Next y

For y = 1 To UBound(InputArray)
InputArray(y, 1) = OutputArray(y, 1)
Next y

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Showing as a sub but same idea:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

Dim selectRange As Range
Dim destRange As Range

With ActiveSheet

    Set selectRange = .Range("A1:C1")
    Set destRange = .Range("A2")

End With

Reverse selectRange, destRange

End Sub

Private Sub Reverse(ByVal selectRange As Range, ByVal destRange As Range)

Dim InputArray() As Variant
Dim OutputArray() As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long

InputArray() = selectRange.Value   '1 to 1 , 1 to 3 so output should be 1 to 3, 1 to 1. Each column becomes row

ReDim OutputArray(1 To UBound(InputArray, 2), 1 To UBound(InputArray, 1))
Dim counter As Long

For x = LBound(InputArray, 1) To UBound(InputArray, 1)

    For y = UBound(InputArray, 2) To LBound(InputArray, 2) Step -1

        counter = counter + 1

        OutputArray(counter, x) = InputArray(x, y)

    Next y

Next x

destRange.Resize(UBound(OutputArray, 1), UBound(OutputArray, 2)) = OutputArray

End Sub
```